# is it possible to pass dynamic values to the tags of xml file from .properties file

Tags: java, xml

I have around 100 plain xml files with repetetive static values. I would like to change them into dynamic by getting values from .properties file so that i can change that value in one place. Is it possible??

**Example of current xmls I have :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bookstore>
  <book category="children">
    <title>Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>  
</bookstore>

**desired change:**

**prop.properties.com**
bookName=Harry Potter
authorName=J K. Rowling
yearValue=2005
priceValue=29.99

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bookstore>`enter code here`

//load properies file

  <book category="children">
    <title>${bookName}</title>
    <author>${authorName}</author>
    <year>${yearValue}</year>
    <price>${priceValue}</price>
  </book>  
</bookstore>
```

Comment: Xml is not a programming language, it is a markup language. This can be done in Java, but I'm not entirely sure what it buys you.

Comment: XML/SGML makes use of *entities* and *entity references* for this purpose; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48266519/xml-configuration-inheritance-avoid-duplications

Comment: thanks for responses but the issue is all the xmls are not in same structure and the repetetive values may not be in the same xml but in all xml files