# Is there any way to inject a variable into a web.xml?

Tags: xml, web.xml

I have web app by using Java EE. I want to run my app for different URL. My app consist of many project and in main project I have web.xml file that decides about URL path. I want to inject form other file like config.xml, a variable to web.xml. Is any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use *entities*, XML's and SGML's mechanism for text variable substitution. The general technique is explained in eg [XML configuration inheritance, avoid duplications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48266519/xml-configuration-inheritance-avoid-duplications) , though you must check if entity expansion is actually supported in your servlet container. [This old JIRA bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STR-3207) would imply it's supported by tomcat, but OTOH maven prominently disables it.