# paremetrize part of xml attribute value

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xinclude

I'm unmarshaling a couple of large XML files.
they have the common part and I decided to write the common parts in separate XML file and then include it using `xi:include` tag.
it looks like this:

```xml
<tag1>
  <tag2>
  </tag2>
  <tag3>
  </tag3>
  <xi:include href = "long/common/part/of/partial/xml/file1"/>
  <xi:include href = "long/common/part/of/partial/xml/file2"/>
</tag1>
```

at this moment I would like to parametrize the `long/common/part`. 
I tried to define a variable using `xsl:variable` like this

```xml
 <xsl:variable name="test">
    "long/common/part/of/partial/xml/"
    </xsl:variable>
```

but the  assigning value to href was a problem, neither the

```xml
<xi:include href = "{$test}"/>
```

or

```xml
<xi:include href = <xsl:value-of select="test"/>
```

wasn't working.
Is there a way to assign value to XML attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing XInclude, XSLT, and ad-hoc `{$var}` syntax (not part of XML) here. What you *can* do to parametrize a `href` value in XInclude elements is to use an *entity reference* (XML's and SGML's mechanism for text substitution variables among other things):

```
<xi:include href="&href-value;"/>
```

where `href-value` must be bound to the string `long/common/part/of/partial/xml/file1` either programmatically, or (preferably) by declaring it in the prolog eg:

```
<!DOCTYPE tag1 [
  <!ENTITY href-value "long/common/part/of/partial/xml/file1">
]>
<tag1>
 <xi:include href = "&href-value;"/>
</tag1>
```

However, since now you're using entity references anyway, you can achieve just the same with just entities, and without XInclude at all:

```
<!DOCTYPE tag1 [
  <!ENTITY common-part SYSTEM "long/common/part/of/partial/xml/file1">
]>
<tag1>
 &common-part;
</tag1>
```

This pulls the *content* of long/common/part/of/partial/xml/file1 into the `common-part` entity, then references that value in content, with the XML parser treating the document as if the replacement value for `common-part` (eg. whatever is stored in `long/common/part/of/partial/xml/file1`) had been specified directly in the document.

Hope this isn't too confusing; there's a general explanation how entities  in XML and SGML work [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48266519/xml-configuration-inheritance-avoid-duplications)

Comment: this is a perfect answer to my question, but if you also can hint me how can I bound href-value programmatically( just a link will be fine) you'll be my hero for today @imhotap

Comment: @zapredelom That depends a bit on which Java API for XML you're using. The most common way to do this is to use the SAX Resolver API as explained in [this article from 2003](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/resolve-custom-xml-entities-with-sax-and-java/). Note the SAX Resolver API requires you to declare an entity with a system or public identifier (like in the way I wrote in the answer with a system identifer eg. file name) and than lets you customize the replacement text for that system or public identifier, but not the replacement text for an entity name as such