# Read values from external properties file into XML file

Tags: xml

I would like to read the values from external properties file into XML.
Say :i have firstname and lastname in properties file and i would like to read them in my XML file.

tried with doctype but no luck

```
<!DOCTYPE project SYSTEM "">
<project name="My Project" default="D:/Apache24/htdocs/">
<property file="build.properties"/>
      <!-- set global properties -->
      <property name="FirstName" value="first"/>
      <property name="LastName" value="last"/>
         <echo message = "First name is = ${FirstName}"/><echo message ="Last name is ${Last Name}"/></target>
   </project>
```

Same XML is shown upon executing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you can get using just XML without using further XML processing tools is using *entities*, XML's mechanism for text substitution variables:

```
<!DOCTYPE project [
  <!ENTITY FirstName "first">
  <!ENTITY LastName "last">
]>
<project name="My Project">
  <property name="FirstName" value="&first;"/>
  <property name="LastName" value="&last;"/>
</project>
```

You can store your entities in an external file as well:

```
<!-- myproperties.dtd -->
<!ENTITY FirstName "first">
<!ENTITY LastName "last">
```

then include it into your main file as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE project SYSTEM "myproperties.dtd">
<project name="My Project">
  <property name="FirstName" value="&first;"/>
  <property name="LastName" value="&last;"/>
</project>
```

You can also further organize your external `myproperties.dtd` file (or whatever name you chose) by having it include a common `globalproperties.dtd` or so and then declare only project-specific entities, or overides global properties/entities, etc.

See also [XML configuration inheritance, avoid duplications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48266519/xml-configuration-inheritance-avoid-duplications).

SGML (on which XML is based) has "short references" which you can use to actually parse a properties file (or many other types of custom text file formats) with the usual syntax eg. lines containing `item=value` pairs. But you wouldn't be able to assign values to entities using that technique as short references (= custom character sequences that SGML replaces by tags or other text) are only recognized in content rather than in DOCTYPE declaration.

Comment: As i stated in my description i have used the DOCTYPE content, but am unable to append/assign the values dynamically to the XML (Say: firstname and lastname from command line etc) those values needs to be append it to the firstname and lastname xml parameters.

Comment: I have created two one .xml and .properties file and tried to read the first,middle & last name from properties file using bean concept. find the code below.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans>
<bean id="configBean" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" systemPropertiesMode="1">
           <property name="location"><value>D:/Apache24/htdocs/ok.properties</value></property>
</bean>
<bean id="Mybean" class="Bean">   
  <property name="first" ref="${first}"/>
  <property name="middle" ref="${middle}"/>
  <property name="last" ref="${last}"/>  
</bean>
</beans>

Comment: @Driod Sorry that is Spring-specific property syntax (has nothing to do with bare XML); I can't help you here