# Is there any tool to perform automated variable substitutions on Config xml files for multiple servers?

Tags: xml, deployment, config, devops

Assume we have N number of environments and we set environment variables on a per-host basis, depending on what environment that hosts in. Thus, is there any tool to replace value of environment variables in an automated way?

Answer (score 0):

SGML and XML have a native mechanism for sharing common parts with individual customizations across multiple files called "entities/entity references". See eg [XML configuration inheritance, avoid duplications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48266519/xml-configuration-inheritance-avoid-duplications) for details.